# Resolving LINQ Error: Missing Query Pattern Implementation

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am receiving a strange LINQ error when trying to filter a collection in my view.

This is my model:

```
public class adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVM
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public PricelistProduct pricelistProduct { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@using Pp.Lib.Models;
@using System.Linq;
@model PpLib.viewModels.admin.adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVM

@{
//get corresponding PricelistProduct
PricelistProduct thisPP = new ProofPixLib.Models.PricelistProduct();
thisPP = (from x in Model.pricelistProduct where x.ProductId == Model.Product.ProductId      select x).FirstOrDefault();   
}
```

the **Model.pricelistProduct** line is underlined in VS and it says the following error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type Pp.Lib.Models.PricelistProduct. 'Where' not found.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**
As requested - here is the code for the PricelistProduct model.

```
public partial class PricelistProduct
{
    public PricelistProduct()
    {
        this.PricelistProductOptions = new List<PricelistProductOption>();
    }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Pricelist Product ID")]
    public int PricelistProductId { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Pricelist ID")]
    public int PricelistId { get; set; } //foregin key
    public virtual Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Product ID")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; } //foreign key
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; } // not a FK but data only
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Use formula")]
    private bool _UsesFormula = true;
    public bool UsesFormula { get { return _UsesFormula; } set { _UsesFormula = value; } }

    private decimal _Price = 0;
    public decimal Price  { get { return _Price; } set { _Price = value; } }

    [Display(Name = "Use discount pricing")]
    private bool _HasDiscountPricing = false;
    public bool HasDiscountPricing { get { return _HasDiscountPricing; } set { _HasDiscountPricing = value; } }

    [Display(Name = "Local shipping price")]
    private decimal _LocalShipPrice = 0;
    public decimal LocalShipPrice { get { return _LocalShipPrice; } set { _LocalShipPrice = value; } }

    [Display(Name = "Intl. shipping price")]
    private decimal _IntlShipPrice = 0;
    public decimal IntlShipPrice { get { return _IntlShipPrice; } set { _IntlShipPrice = value; } }

    [Display(Name = "Item is taxable")]
    private bool _isTaxable = true;
    public bool isTaxable { get { return _isTaxable; } set { _isTaxable = value; } }

    public virtual List<PricelistProductOption> PricelistProductOptions { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Does it also say Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?  If so you should include using System.Linq.

Comment: Thanks but I have @using System.Linq; at the top of my view.

Comment: Can you post code for PricelistProduct? Does it implement IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PricelistProduct` class doesn't implement `IEnumerable` or `IQuerable` interfaces, other words it's not a collection to query over it.
Maybe it should be `Model.pricelistProduct.PricelistProductOptions` in your query or your view model should be a collection?

Consecutive assignments don't make sense as well:

```
@{
//get corresponding PricelistProduct
PricelistProduct thisPP = new ProofPixLib.Models.PricelistProduct();
thisPP = ..;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are correct - there was no need to Enumerate this - the parent which called this partial already did that. I feel dumb!